# Cheapest way to use a MySql Database on Microsoft Azure

Tags: server, mysql, database, azure, business-models

I am currently evaluating features of [Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/), and want to try their [Azure Database for MySQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/mysql/) service in a little test project. I just need a very basic database with minimal performance and no backups etc. However, prices seem to be north of 200$/Month.

Currently I have a hard time to find out the pricing for an MySql or MariaDb database. The prices seem also to be dependent on which way you try to get them:

- Using the "Pricing Calculator" at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=mysql returns about $60 (East US, Basic Tier, 1 Core, running for 1 Month, a few storage GB's)
- Using the "Pricing Details" Tab at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/mysql/ for a similar model (especially 1 VCORE) I get something in the range of $25.
- Actually trying to create a server, in the portal ("Create MySQL server)" at https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.MySQLServer/ I get something in the range of $260, however for 4 cores (which I can not change there).

**Do I really need a full Db Server (with dedicated processor cores) and Database? Or is there a cheaper option to run something like a serverless MySql database or from within a container?**

*Note: The wording of this question is based on feedback from [Are questions about Azure pricing off-topic?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1638/are-questions-about-azure-pricing-off-topic)*